# Buck IC (XL4015) feedback logic

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, buck, feedback

The [datasheet](https://www.electronicoscaldas.com/datasheet/XL4015_XLSEMI.pdf) for the XL4015 has the following information about the feedback loop:

- The threshold feedback voltage is 1.25V
- The switching frequency is 180Khz
- If the feedback voltage exceeds 3.3V, the converter shuts down until the feedback voltage drops to 0.8V

My question is: How exactly is the feedback voltage converted to a PWM signal? More specifically:

- Does the IC measure the feedback voltage every cycle?
- Does the magnitude of the feedback voltage (besides < 1.25, > 1.25, and > 3.3) affect the resulting PWM? E.g. does it matter whether the feedback is 1.3V or 1.4V?
- If the above answers are Yes and No, is the loop as simple as:

```
shutdown = False
while (True):
  if (FB > 3.3):
    shutdown = True
    switch(OFF)
  else if (shutdown):
    if (FB < 0.8):
      shutdown = False
      switch(ON)
    else:
      switch(OFF)
  else if (FB > 1.25):
    switch(OFF)
  else if (FB < 1.25):
    switch(ON)
```

Comment: The datasheet shows the inner block diagram of the chip, which answers all your bullet points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: How exactly is the feedback voltage converted to a PWM signal?

The way the PWM signal is created is well documented, but in a nutshell, the error signal, modulates a high frequency ramp signal in such a way that the duty cycle is adjusted every period. That is accomplished by comparing the error signal with the high frequency triangular wave:

[image]

[source](https://microchipdeveloper.com/pwr3101:transition-to-digital-pwm)

Notice how the pulse-width at the output of the comparator changes in response to the two signal it has at its input—the output still preserves the high frequency (period) of the triangular/ramp signal, but the pulse-width variation contains the information of how much greater or smaller the low-frequency signal is with respect to the ramp. In a Buck regulator, if there is a large positive error, then you'd expect the pulse width to be large since it means that that the output voltage is much lower than the setpoint.

Now, that is a high level explanation but the control algorithm is actually more complex than that as it also incorporates the inductor current information (i.e., current mode control), but the idea still holds (with some more details).

> Does the IC measure the feedback voltage every cycle?

Yes, the output voltage is tied permanently to the feedback loop, so it is continuously monitored. However, the pulse width is adjusted once per cycle  and that is due to having an SR Latch block that prevents "glitches" from passing over to the switching transistor.

[image]

> Does the magnitude of the feedback voltage (besides < 1.25, > 1.25, and > 3.3) affect the resulting PWM? E.g. does it matter whether the feedback is 1.3V or 1.4V?

The goal of the feedback control is to bring the VFB to 1.25V. Obviously, if the converter is in shutdown mode, it won't regulate the output voltage. As long as the converter is on, the PWM width will be adjusted as explained before.